# is there any way to get the request data in Primefaces ajaxStatus like jsf.ajax.addOnEvent

Tags: ajax, jsf, events, primefaces

I want to modify All Ajax request  data .
i am using **p:ajaxStatus**  for monitor ajax requests .
is there any way to get the data like below for primefaces ajax status

```
jsf.ajax.addOnEvent (function( data )){

    console.log(data) ;// here i can view and modify data 
});
---------------------------------------------------------
<p:ajaxStatus onstart="jsfun()" onsuccess="jsfun()" /> //is there any way to
                                                // get data like above
```

Comment: I need to add extra param to request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To modify requests' data:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(document).on('pfAjaxSend', function(event, xhr, source, errorThrown) {
            xhr.pfSettings.data += '&amp;my_param=my_value';
        });
    })
</script>
```

Obligatory warning: pfAjaxSend is an undocumented event, not a part of the official API. AFAIK there's no way to do this without relying on this event or some implementation details. I did check that pfAjaxSend is present in PF 5-6 though.

In case you're still interested in ajaxStatus' arguments, you can get them like this:

```
 <p:ajaxStatus onstart="console.log(arguments);" onsuccess="console.log(arguments);" />
```

Inspect the arguments in your browser's dev tools.